# change template dynamically in typo3

Tags: typo3

I am getting in this stuck needs help from you all. I am getting 2 version(with different content) for homepage, but a PAGE only have 1 template to show (as I know so far). I wonder that if there is any way to change from template1 to template2 if I still standing on homepage.

Regards,
Chanh

Comment: Please be more clear about your intentions. You have two templates and want to use one template on the home page and one on all the other pages? Are you using the TEMPLATE cObject or FLUIDTEMPLATE?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the fact is that you have to have a flag and switch it then reload the homepage.
Once reloaded check the flag and set the right template based on it.